# Multilingual MySQL Database Structure for huge data

Tags: mysql, database, localization

I'm looking for some advice regarding a multilingual MySQL Database Structure which can handle huge amounts of data.
We are using the following method at the moment:

```
Articles  <- Article_translations -> Languages
id           id                      id
date         language_id (fk)        locale
category     article_id  (fk)   
             content
```

Ok, lets just say we've got like 100.000 Articles and 5 languages...well..you see the problem. The larger the data, the slower the database (just a guess here, but complex JOIN queries which are absolutely necessary probably won't be O(log(n)) but rather something like O(n^2)).

Our current solution is to split the Article_translations into [locale]_article_translations (e.g. en_us_article_translation) in which case we would need to synchronize the structure between those tables easily. Is this an appropriate method to solve this problem or are there better ones? If this is a good solution, is there something out there which could help to monitor changes (only structural, no data synch!) and synchronize those structures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming if you tune your query properly

- Check query execution plan with the large set of data
- Make sure if you use DB level parameter as "large set" instead of row level
- See if you make your table denormalized(or vise versa) enough.

I would suggest belows although I am not sure which version of MySQL your are using

- Partitioing at DB level
- Fast hard disk in the DB server

I would suggest to use partitioning first and then you might consider to upgrade hard disk.

**Partitioning**

Partitioning is data spliting provided by database level.
Based on your query usage, you can divide data, for example, by language in your case.
The good thing to use DB partitioning is that

- it could be treated by a single table from application side
- Depends on the data volumn and frequncy, it can be rearranged by DB level. No impact to the apps.

**Hard disk quality**

Also the hard disk quality is important to handle large set of data.
Even if the query is tunned at best, if you deal with lots of data in a single query, you need fast data access. But this is costy.

Comment: wow, mysql partitioning looks very interesting. I'll give it a closer look! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you are half right, larger data slower database, but if the DB don't have a good design it will be slow even with small data.

I can't tell you what is the best way or the best solution, remember that you need to make multiple things to find the "best solution".  I just can recommend you some tools and some tips that could help you.

First, check your index, index types, no only PK and FK, you need also see which type of index do you need, I.E, do you need text index? or hashtree??.

Check also your engine, MyISAM or InnoDB?.  You said that you split the table, check [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11990/splitting-tables-in-mysql-good-practice) about split.

Also your query will be faster if you avoid things `like  '%word%'` remember that a bad query will make a huge difference about time of response.

You can use `Show create table` or D`escribe select ......` or `explain` to see what's going on, or use the command `benchmark` to see the approximate time of a function that you are applying to improve it

Some tools for MySQL I'll recommend you to take a look to this program that will help you with this part of performance.

- Mysqlslap (it's like benchmark but you can customize more the result).
- SysBench (test CPUperformance, I/O performance, mutex contention, memory speed, database performance).
- Mysqltuner (with this you can analize general statistics, Storage engine Statistics, performance metrics).
- mk-query-profiler (perform analysis of a SQL Statement).
- mysqldumpslow (good to know witch queries are causing problems).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We are relying completely on PKs and FKs altough there are some exceptions (like seo-optimization /article/test-article and fulltext-search).
I will have a look into those tools which seem to be quite interesting!

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention. Currently it is InnoDB but we are switching to a mysql cluster solution soon